# Django and HTML cannot start video from a specified time

Tags: django, html5-video

I am trying to start playing a video from a specific location using Django:

```
<video controls autoplay id='vid' muted >
 <source src="{% static 'vids/videoplayback.mp4#t=10,30' %}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This gives an error

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/vids/videoplayback.mp4%23t%3D10%2C30
> 404 (Not Found)

as it seems Django automatically escaping the special characters is the culprit. Removing the **#t=10,30** will autoplay the video without any issue.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set attrs as strings with the mustache-syntax e.g.: `{{ 'random string' }}`. Like this:

```
<video controls autoplay id='vid' muted >
 <source src="{% static 'vids/videoplayback.mp4' %}{{ '#t=10,30' }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```