# Django do not auto escape characters

Tags: python, django

I have a code to play video in a django app

```
<video controls autoplay id='vid' muted >
 <source src="{% static 'vids/videoplayback.mp4#t=10,30' %}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The problem is that django auto escapes the characters and gives an error

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/vids/videoplayback.mp4%23t%3D10%2C30 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `<source src="{% static 'vids/videoplayback.mp4' %}#t=10,30" type="video/mp4">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and HTML cannot start video from a specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581662/django-and-html-cannot-start-video-from-a-specified-time)

Answer (score 3):

The `static` will urlencode the string, so this is not a *fragment*, but a hash sign (`#`) as part of the file name. If you want to set a fragment, you do that *after* the [**`{% static … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static):

```
<source src="{% static 'vids/videoplayback.mp4' %}#t=10,30" type="video/mp4">
```